# How to initialise value to 1 if it is null

Tags: apex

I am working on apex class where I am fetching a number field, can anyone help me out in initializing number field to 1 if it is null.

I want to initialize DCS_Auto_Number__c field to 1 if it is null.

My class is below

```
buildCycleList = [SELECT Name, (SELECT Id, DCS_Auto_Number__c FROM Action_Items__r order by DCS_Auto_Number__c desc limit 1) FROM Build_Cycle__c WHERE Id IN: buildCycleId];

        for(Build_Cycle__c bObj : buildCycleList){
            Integer length2 = integer.valueOf(bObj.Action_Items__r[0].DCS_Auto_Number__c);
            for(Action_Item__c cObj : actionItemList){
                if(bObj.Id == cObj.DCS_Build_Cycle__c){
                         length2++;
                        cObj.DCS_Auto_Number__c = length2; 
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the default value for `DCS_Auto_Number__c` ? Set the default value as `1`.

Comment: @VijayGanji, I already set default value to 1 while creating field but the issue is when I am inserting bulk records then count is not increasing at all but if I insert records one by one then auto number field is incrementing, I am unable to find the issue here

Answer (score 1):

> initialize DCS_Auto_Number__c field to 1 if it is null.

this states straight forward

```
if(bObj.Action_Items__r[0].DCS_Auto_Number__c == null){
    bObj.Action_Items__r[0].DCS_Auto_Number__c = 1;
}
```

I strongly recommend you at least to pass [Apex Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_intro)

Comment: thanks for helping me out here, actually in my code I am looking at DCS_Auto_Number__c field, while creating record this field will be null, so in mycode if it is null I want to set it to 1, can you help me out in this issue here

Comment: @what do you mean "creating" ? inserting, or making a new instance of class ?

Comment: actually I am inserting bulk records using data loader but count is showing always 1 on every record, it is not at all incrementing actually,If I manually create records one by one then count is incrementing